# javafx - how to disable events fired not from the user

Tags: events, javafx

i have a little problem with javafx. i added a change listener like this:

```
private final ChangeListener<String> pageItemSelected = new ChangeListener<String>()
{
@Override
public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue){
    pageGotSelected(newValue);
}
};
```

now to the problem: if i change an page item like this:

```
 guiPageList.setValue(model.getCurrentTargetPage());
```

the event gets also(as it get by selecting something with the mouse or key) fired. is there a way to disable the event firing or another way?
i need the event only, if the element got selected by the user and not if i change it with the setValue() function...
perhaps consuming the event, but i don´t know what kind of event this would be.

thanks in advance!!!

Comment: How are you adding pageItemSelected to listeners?

Comment: do you mean this:

guiPageList.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(pageItemSelected);

?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can temporarily remove the listener and add it again:

```
guiPageList.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().removeListener(pageItemSelected);
guiPageList.setValue(model.getCurrentTargetPage());
guiPageList.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(pageItemSelected);
```

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively you could decorate the listener with another listener implementation, the code would be something like:

```
class InvalidationListenerEventBlocker implements InvalidationListener {
    InvalidationListener decoratedListener;
    boolean block;
    public void invalidated(Observable observable) {
        if(!block) {
            decoratedListener.invalidated(observable);
        }
    }
}
```

Add a setter for the block boolean and send the listener in through the constructor.  Set block to true to stop events.

Answer (score 1):

This is very old question, but I came to some solution I personally use, that's reusable and does not require storing a reference to the listener (but it needs a reference to the exposing/muffling property thou).

So first the concept: we're going to create lambda (`InvalidationListener`), that is going to be called only if  above mentioned exposing/muffling property is set to true/false. For that we are going to define another functional interface that provides described behavior:

```java
@FunctionalInterface
private interface ManageableInvalidationListener
extends InvalidationListener {

    public static InvalidationListener exposing(
            BooleanProperty expose,
            ManageableInvalidationListener listener) {
        return ob -> {
            if (expose.get()) {
                listener.invalidate(ob);
            }
        };
    }

    public static InvalidationListener muffling(
            BooleanProperty muffle,
            ManageableInvalidationListener listener) {
        return ob -> {
            if (!muffle.get()) {
                listener.invalidated(ob);
            }
        }
    }

    public abstract void invalidated(Observable ob);
}
```

This interface defines two static methods we're going to use in our code. We pass a steering property as first argument (it will tell if listener should be called) and actual implementation to be performed, when it will be called. Please note, that there is no need to extend `InvalidationListener`, but I'd like to keep `ManageableInvalidationListener` in sync with `InvalidationListener`.

So we would call `exposing` if we need to create a (manageabale) listener that would notify the (invalidation) listener if `expose` property has value of `true`. In other case we would create the listener with `muffling`, if `true` of the steering property would mean, well, to muffle the notification.

How to use it?

```java
    //- Let's make life easier and import expose method statically
    import static ManageableInvalidationListener.exposing;

// ...

    //- This is the steering property.
    BooleanProperty notify = new SimpleBooleanProperty(true);

    //- This is our main property with the listener.
    ObjectProperty<Foobar> foobar = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    //- Let's say we are going to notify the listener, if the
    //  notify property is set to true.
    foobar.addListener(exposing(notify, ob -> {
        //- Here comes the InvalidListener code.
    }));
```

And then somewhere in the code:

```java
    //- Listener will be notified as usual.
    foobar.set(new Foobar());

    //- Now temporarily disable notifications.
    notify.set(false);
    //- The listener will not get the notification this time.
    foobar.set(new Foobar());
    //- Re-enable notifications.
    notify.set(true);
```

Hope this somehow helps. You're free to use the code in this post as pleases you.